# Dates and times are wrong in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building a blog site that logs the time and date when an entry is posted and stored in MongoDB. When I run it on my local machine, the date and time are correct. But when I hosted it on Heroku, the date shows it is 8 hours ahead of my time. Why is this and how can I fix it? Here's the link to the app:

[Blog App](https://protected-basin-36050.herokuapp.com/)

Also here is the code that is responsible for posting an entry and logging the date and time:

```
app.post("/compose", (req, res) => {
  const postTitle = req.body.postTitle;
  const postBody = req.body.postBody;

  let date = new Date();
  let postDate = date.toLocaleString('en-US');

  const post = new Post({
    date: postDate,
    title: postTitle,
    content: postBody
  });

  post.save(err => {
    if (!err) {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `toLocaleString` only formats the string given, but the time it displays will still be tied to the time of the server/client it runs on. Since the two machines you tried it on aren't in the same time zone, this happens. You should consider storing the `Date` object itself so it is UTC and invariant from any server you will run your program on. Alternatively, you could pass the timezone you want to `toLocaleString` like so: `new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});`

Comment: Store in Zulu/UTC (`.toISOString()`) then when you render it you can do so in whatever timezone you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment was getting a bit lengthy, so I'll post it as an answer here.

---

`toLocaleString` only formats the string it is given, but the time it displays will still be tied to the system time of the server/client it runs on. 
Since the two machines you tried it on aren't in the same time zone, this happens.

You may consider storing the `Date` object itself so it is invariant from any server you will run your program on. Additionnally, it will let you do Date operations more easily should you have the need to.

Alternatively, you could pass the timezone you want to `toLocaleString` like so:

```
  let date = new Date();
  let postDate = date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});

  const post = new Post({
    date: postDate,
    title: postTitle,
    content: postBody
  });
```

---

You will find more information on `toLocaleString` in the [official Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

You will also find a comprehensive list of timezone names you can use in this wikipedia entry: [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). You may use any timezone for which the status is `Canonical` or `Alias`. Any other timezone will throw a `RangeError` exception.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But if I did it the alternative way by passing a timezone, it will still only log my local timezone if someone from a different timezone used the app, right? I want to make it some that no matter where in the world the app is used from heroku, it will reflect the local time and date. Is that done through storing the Date object?

Comment: Yes, if you want people to see their local time, the easiest and most natural way to do so is to store the Date object directly. You deliver this object to the front-end, and only then use `toLocaleString` to format the date however you'd like.

Comment: Okay great. So when you say store the Date object directly, you mean storing it into the the "post" object directly rather than passing it in through a variable, right? Sorry for these n00b questions. I'm just trying to make things clear. lol.

Comment: Yes, `let postDate = new Date()`.

Comment: Sure, don't hesitate to pop by if any other problem arises (or just create another question if it needs another lengthy answer).

Comment: So I did what you said. Once the Date was posted  on the back-end, I used "toLocaleString" on the front-end to manipulate the format through the DOM. I created a separate JS file for that purpose.

`let dateFormat = document.querySelector(".post-date");

if (dateFormat !== null) {
  dateFormat = dateFormat.textContent;
  dateFormat.toLocaleString('en-US');
} `

Yet it's still giving me the same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188858/discussion-between-madward-and-envincebal).